# Limit OPA Rego to a single rule solution

Tags: open-policy-agent

If I have a rule like this: ([playground](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/FW9BdzC5Fg))

```
package play

rule[message] {
    max_index := count(input)-1

    some i

    index_a = i
    index_b = (max_index-i)
    point_a := input[index_a]
    point_b := input[index_b]

    point_a != point_b

    message := sprintf("%d (%s) and %d (%s)", [index_a, point_a, index_b, point_b])
}
```

and have this input:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

I get multiple solutions to my rule, e.g.

```
"0 (a) and 2 (c)",
"2 (c) and 0 (a)"
```

Is there a way I can stop OPA searching once any solution as been found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today there's no way to ask OPA to stop after a single answer.  The algorithms support it, but it's just not something people seem to need.

You can certainly ask for the first answer OPA finds by turning your set into an array and grabbing the first element.  [Playground](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/g6kjIfjkw8)

```
array_rule = [message | rule[message]]
first = array_rule[0]
```

Alternatively, if order is important, you could write your logic as an array comprehension to start and then grab the first element again.  [Playground](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/ntdntlxjX7)

```
array_rule = [message |
    max_index := count(input)-1

    some i

    index_a = i
    index_b = (max_index-i)
    point_a := input[index_a]
    point_b := input[index_b]

    point_a != point_b

    message := sprintf("%d (%s) and %d (%s)", [index_a, point_a, index_b, point_b])
]

first = array_rule[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. It's not really something I need either, I was able to use a set to remove some duplicate messages I was getting. Just interested to know if such a thing existed. Cheers.